# PHP OOP Design - separating 'characteristics' from functions

Tags: php, oop

In the below code, I have a class called Dog. The dog can do many things, such as bark or sit. The dog also has characteristics, such as breed, sex, or color.

This code could get messy in the future if you have a dog with many characteristics and many functions, so what is the OOP-appropriate way to separate things out, such as characteristics vs functions of the dog?

Would it be just creating other classes such as `class DogCharacteristics` `class DogFunctions` and having a parent class called `Dog`?

I have read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-7oohabits/ so it got me thinking how to implement good OOP habits.

```
class Dog
{
    private $breed;

    public function getBreed()
    {
        return $this->breed;
    }

    public function setBreed($breed)
    {
        $this->breed = $breed;
    }


    public function getDogInfo()
    {
        return "This dog is " . $this->getBreed();
    }

    public function bark()
    {
        return "The dog barks!";
    }

    public function sit()
    {
        return "The dog sits.";
    }
}
```

How would you improve the above code so that it adheres to good OOP habits and separates out a dog's function vs characteristic?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches, but one we see often these days is traits. Using traits, you can split your code into different files while keeping the whole idea together. The problem with that is that your method's trait file will flash with errors if you use an IDE because it won't know where to get the properties from.

```
class Dog
{
    use DogCharacteristics;
    use DogMethods;
}

trait DogCharacteristics
{
    var $breed;
    var $color;
}

trait DogMethods
{
    public function walk(){}
    public function bark(){}
}
```

It is far from the best approach, but it is one that is used a lot in frameworks today.

One thing that strikes me is the following:

- This code could get messy in the future if you have a dog with many characteristics and many functions

This is a bad approach. Over optimization of code is usually not a good approach. You should focus on writting clear, documented code with unit tests which will allow you to refactor later on instead of thinking right off the start how to best do it.

Comment: Another thing i forgot to mention since you are talking about PHP7. PHP7 should have property accessor functions which will greatly simplify entity code by chopping the "getXYZ" and "setXYZ" functions down to a simplified version. So don't worry too much, this is normal and doesn't mean you have badly coded if you have too many properties in your entities

Comment: And another thing, remember not to fall into the Liskov Susbstitution trap when a Dog is an Animal thus i'll move some of the code to a subclass. This is usually bad practice and eventually promotes bad coding practices and confusion around your app.